# How to remove values in conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I have conditional formatting rules applied to a workbook. When a user selects No in Row 1 for example, Row 2 and subsequent rows get greyed out. When user selects Yes in Row 1, Row 2 and subsequent rows have cells active. This part is working fine. The problem is when user selects No in Row 1, it also has text also appear as No in greyed Row 2 and subsequent greyed out rows. What conditional formatting can I apply to stop having text appear as No in the greyed out rows? I don't want any text appearing in these greyed out rows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's impossible to tell for us without examples of how the initial state would b, what code makes it change and if the `No` selection is dependent on a previous `Yes` selection or not. If that's the case you need vba, otherwise add a simple condition to the code for `IF(Cell_value ="no",...`

Answer (score 1):

If understood correctly, to prevent from appearing in the greyed out rows when ***No** is selected in Row 1*, try,

1. Use *conditional formatting* and *cell formatting*.
2. Select the cells in Row 2 and subsequent rows where you don't want
   the text to appear.
3. Go to *Conditional Formatting*.
4. Select "New Rule" from the dropdown menu. In the "New Formatting
   Rule" dialog box, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to
   format".
5. In the "Format values where this formula is true" field, enter:
   `=AND($A$1="No",ROW()>1)`
6. In the Font tab, select the color as *white* (or the same as the
   background color) to hide the text.